# Pandas 'read_csv' giving an error, in one specific directory only

Tags: python, csv, pandas, module, kaggle

I was attempting to follow a [pandas/sklearn/kaggle tutorial](http://ahmedbesbes.com/how-to-score-08134-in-titanic-kaggle-challenge.html), and barely got a dozen lines when I stumbled over over one of the simplest commands in python:

Code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 100
pd.options.display.max_rows   = 100

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as pd

import numpy as np


#Cell 3
data = pd.read_csv('./Data/train.csv')

data.head()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KaggleTitanic00.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv('./Data/train.csv')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

A command that only gives an error in *that directory*:

```
~/Python/Tutorials/SKlearn$ python Chapter4--Test-12.py
Number of spam messages: 747
Number of ham messages: 4825
['spam' 'spam' 'ham' ..., 'ham' 'ham' 'ham']
Prediction: spam. Message: Ur cash-balance is currently 500 pounds - to maximize ur cash-in now send GO to 86688 only 150p/msg. CC 08718720201 HG/Suite342/2Lands Row/W1J6HL
Prediction: spam. Message: December only! Had your mobile 11mths+? You are entitled to update to the latest colour camera mobile for Free! Call The Mobile Update Co FREE on 08002986906
Prediction: ham. Message: Just normal only here :)
Prediction: ham. Message: How would my ip address test that considering my computer isn't a minecraft server
Prediction: ham. Message: Ü collecting ur laptop then going to configure da settings izzit?
```

I have absolutely no idea what's wrong. The code is identical to the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

By reimporting as `pd` you overwrite `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Understood. Thank you.